# When I execute a prepared statement to select rows in a db table, does pdo "fetch" the records and caches it?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

When I execute a prepared statement to select rows in a db table, does pdo "fetch" the records and caches it?
i.e. If I perform a fetch after executing a "select" statement, does pdo perform multiple db calls for each record I want fetched or does it simply fetch each record from its cache? (assuming it has cache)

tnx.

Comment: maybe related or might shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459793/php-pdo-how-long-are-prepared-mysql-queries-cached

Comment: @Ghost Tnx for the link but it appears that that discussion revolves around increasing performance when exe select statements. My question pertains to the pdo fetch method called after the select statement was exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask ***does pdo perform multiple db calls for each record*** if you mean a database connection or query by saying *calls*, then no. the way it works pdo opens the connection, query once then if you use `fetchAll()` it gets all the  values at once while `fetch()` will get one value at the the time.

The caching you are referring when using `prepare()` a and `execute()` for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information.

Unless you are fetching huge amount of records (into the memory) you should not be concern with the cost of using fetch.

Sooo.. to answer your question PDO will not cache fetch , it will be stored into memory.

Comment: fetch will not send a query to the database every time. fetch just limits the amount of records returned by PHP.

Comment: yes exactly fetch moves the row pointer to the next row each time it is called

Comment: Aah, so if do a `while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }` then it does not interact with the MySQL server, but with PHP cache?

Comment: @meda Thank you very much for the time and effort to provide me with a very useful answer :-)

Comment: You are very much welcome and intereseting question , you got my vote ;)